# Git errors with commits

Tags: git

I tried to commit something on my openshift account and it got me out of quota (was not carefull I know). Now I cannot go back front and push anythin because I got the following error

```
git error: unable to create temporary ???????? ?????? file: remote: fatal: failed to write object
```

I tried to revert checkout etc and my branch looks like this

```
 04094d5 (HEAD, master) getting back
| * a06b5c5 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Lightening template
| * 00b8ac3 removed files
| * bb5a83c Adding again
| * ef57d1a Setting up admin template
|/
```

ef57d1a was the one that did the thing...git push gives me the following error

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh:openshiftsshkey/folder/~/git/beta.git/'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

But I don't want to change the files locally on my pc. What should I do?

DAMN!!! It has allready deleted some of my local files...What should I do??

Comment: First of all copy the folder and create a backup in your computer. Next do git stash (that will save your files modifications to git special stash) after that do a git pull and on top of the new data do git stash apply.

Comment: I did...thank god...

Comment: After git pull it says
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

Comment: Try to use git checkout master and if you want to see all the branches use git branch -a

Comment: @Apostolos you just take a backup of your repo (safe side) and do "git pull origin/master" .It will take you to the top of HEAD and then you again try to resume your changes and commit.

Comment: Thank you all, I had to tidy my openshift server since i got out of quota...It's the free one for testing. Thank you community